# Checking if '?' is present anywhere in string data frame python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, lambda

**Background**: I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'text': ["yeah!", "tomorrow? let's go", "today will do"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['text'].apply(str)
```

**Output**:

```
    text
0   yeah!
1   tomorrow? let's go
2   today will do
```

**Goal**:

1) check each row to determine if '?' is present and return a boolean (return `True` if `?` is anywhere in the `text` column and `False` if no `?` is present

2) create a new column with the results

**Desired outpu**t:

```
    text                result
0   yeah!               False
1   tomorrow? let's go  True
2   today will do       False
```

**Problem**: 
I am using the code below

```
df['Result'] = df.text.apply(lambda t: t[-1]) is "?"
```

**Actual Output**:

```
    text                result
0   yeah!               False
1   tomorrow? let's go  False
2   today will do       False
```

**Question**: How do I alter my code to achieve 1) of my goal?

Comment: This will work `df['result'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: True if '?' in x else False)` You probably need to understand how lambdas work. Jezrael answer is generally better than using lambda to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regex `?` is special character, so need escape it or use `regex=False` in [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df['result'] = df['text'].astype(str).str.contains('\?')
```

Or:

```
df['result'] = df['text'].astype(str).str.contains('?', regex=False)
```

Or:

```
df['result'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: '?' in x )

print (df) 
                 text  result
0               yeah!   False
1  tomorrow? let's go    True
2       today will do   False
```